# How to implement a Views 3 exposed filter in block as a list of links, and update the view via ajax?

Tags: 7, ajax, views, navigation

I need to create a views exposed filter that is displayed as a list of links, and updates the view via Ajax.  I've tried using [Better Exposed Filters](http://drupal.org/project/better_exposed_filters) and it will display the filter as links, but without ajax.  I've tried to figure out how to theme the default views select element (which is ajaxified) as a list of links, but haven't found a good way to go about this yet.  Any suggestions would be much appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this patch: https://drupal.org/node/1268150#comment-7393486, it's for better exposed filters and it's to make it work with AJAX.

As for the default views select element, try using an argument.

Comment: I can confirm that I use that patch to do exactly as you say but with checkboxes.